# scatter chart high number of points

Tags: highcharts

I am using following code to insert points in the scatter chart:

```
series: [
 {
  name: 'Machine 1',color: '#0000FF',marker: {radius: 3, symbol: 'circle'},
   data: [
     {x: Date.UTC(2020,10,07,00,00,00), y: 0, prod_type: 'Production', number_of_cycles: '10',},
     {x: Date.UTC(2020,10,07,00,01,00), y: 0, prod_type: 'Production', number_of_cycles: '11',}
    ]
 },
 {
  name: 'Machine 2',color: '#00FF00',marker: {radius: 3, symbol: 'circle'},
   data: [
     {x: Date.UTC(2020,10,07,00,00,00), y: 1, prod_type: 'Setup', number_of_cycles: '1',},
     {x: Date.UTC(2020,10,07,00,01,00), y: 1, prod_type: 'Setup', number_of_cycles: '2',}
    ]
 }
]
```

This works but when I put a high number of points (more than 1,000) into one section data[], the chart shows nothing.

Thanks for your help

Jan

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the `turboThreshold` option:

> **turboThreshold: number**
>
> When a series contains a data array that is longer than this, only one
> dimensional arrays of numbers, or two dimensional arrays with x and y
> values are allowed. Also, only the first point is tested, and the rest
> are assumed to be the same format. This saves expensive data checking
> and indexing in long series. Set it to 0 disable.
>
> Note: In boost mode turbo threshold is forced. Only array of numbers
> or two dimensional arrays are allowed. Defaults to 1000.

You can map your data to a simpler format, like: `[x, y]` or change the value of turbo threshold.

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.turboThreshold